# moment.js error, sometimes ignores the day

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a problem with moment.js and it's that I have two dates (initial and final) when I initialize the dates, the initial is fine but the final date is not, moment.js ignores the day part of the date ,I set "2020-10-05T09:00" but in the console I get "2020-10T17:15Z", as you can see it doesn't have the day part.

Here is my code

```
const ini = moment("2020-10-01T09:00");
const fin = moment("2020-10-05T09:00");
var diff = fin.diff(ini, 'seconds');
console.log(fin);
```

The console prints:

> {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: "2020-10T09:00Z", _isUTC: false, _pf: {…}, _locale: x, …}

Comment: It shoud be `console.log(diff)`, isn't it?

Comment: This seems to work fine for me, if I log `fin._i` I get `2020-10-05T09:00`.

Comment: It also work fine for me. Result: `Moment<2020-10-05T09:00:00-03:00>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the format of your date as the second parameter to [create a momentjs object based on your date](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).

Also, after calculating the `fin.diff(ini, 'seconds')`, you'll need to log `diff` to get the number of seconds;

```js
const ini = moment("2020-10-01T09:00", 'YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm');
const fin = moment("2020-10-05T09:00", 'YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm');
var diff = fin.diff(ini, 'seconds');

console.log(diff);
// output: 345600
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: no need to pass, if he log the `diff`, the result will still be the same as this..

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i still get the same problem even with your solution, it's  like  it crash with the date upper than today, i really don't undertand why. but i still get "2020-10T09:00Z"

Comment: @YeisonM Please clarify the issue, if you run my code-snippet, it wil show the diff in seconds.

Comment: mmmm it's ok , i was printing another value, my mistake